# Таблица с промежуточными итогами

Tags: powerbi

Есть большая таблица с данными вида:

- яблоки, зеленые, в коробке, 10 шт
- яблоки, красные, в коробке, 20 шт
- яблоки, красные, в коробке, 15 шт
- яблоки, красные, в пакете, 10 шт
- ....

всё это выводится в итоговую таблицу вида:

1. яблоки зеленые в коробках, 100 шт
2. яблоки красные в коробках, 150 шт
3. **итого яблок в коробках, 250**
4. яблоки зеленые в пакетах, 200 шт
5. яблоки красные в пакетах, 250 шт
6. **итого яблок в пакетах, 450**
7. итого яблок всего, 700

Вопрос, возможно ли сделать промежуточные итоги в таблице по определенному атрибуту? То, что находится в 3 и 6 строке.
Сейчас итожится только по всем данным (строка 7)

Если табличный виджет это не позволяет, как это можно сделать иначе?

Answer (score 0):

Решается использованием виджета Матрица